# Sending current page url to database

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I am attempting to write a query to send the current page the user is on to my database table, click_count. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because right now I am not getting any errors in my error report. None of the queries are being executed and none of the echoed errors are showing.

I am not sure if the issue is with the way I am building the session or not. `$_SESSION['page'] = $curPage;`. What I am trying to do is do a `SELECT` query to see if there is a record and if not then `INSERT` one and then from that point `UPDATE` the `page_count` every time the user goes on the page.

Does anyone see anything that is pointing out that may be wrong?

Table click_count:

```
click_count
CREATE TABLE `click_count` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `page_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `page_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Code:

```
session_start();
//create current page constant
$curPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
//echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
//set number of clicks variable to 0
$clicks = 0;

   //set current page as session variable
   $_SESSION['page'] = $curPage;
//do not recount if page currently loaded
if($_SESSION['page'] != $curPage) {


    $click_sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM click_count
    WHERE user_id = ?
    AND page_url = ?
    ";
    if (!$click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_sql)) {
        $click_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $curPage));
        $click_stmt_rows = $click_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $page_count = $click_stmt->rowCount();
        if (!$click_stmt->errno) {
            echo "Error selecting page count.";
        }
    } else if ($page_count == 0) {
        //try to create new record and set count for new page to 1
         //output error message if problem encountered
            $click_insert_stmt = "
            INSERT INTO click_count 
            (page_url, page_count)
            VALUES(?, ?)";

         if(!$click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_insert_stmt)) {
            $click_insert_stmt->execute(array($curPage, 1));
            echo "Could not create new click counter.";
         }
         else {
            $clicks = 1;
         }
    } else {
    //get number of clicks for page and add 1     fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)
        while($click_row = $click_insert_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
            $clicks = $row['page_count'] + 1;
            //update click count in database;
            //report error if not updated

            $click_update_stmt = "
            UPDATE click_count
            SET page_count=page_count+1
            WHERE page_url = ?
            ";
            if(!$click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_update_stmt)) {
                $click_update_stmt->execute(array($curPage)); 
                echo "Could not save new click count for this page.";
         }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
$curPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$clicks = 0;

    $click_sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM click_count
    WHERE user_id = ?
    AND page_url = ?
    ";
        $click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_sql);
        $click_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $curPage));
        $click_stmt_rows = $click_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $page_count = $click_stmt->rowCount();
    if ($page_count == 0) {
        //try to create new record and set count for new page to 1
         //output error message if problem encountered
            $click_insert_stmt = "
            INSERT INTO click_count 
            (user_id, page_url, page_count)
            VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

         if(!$click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_insert_stmt)) {
            $click_insert_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $curPage, 1));
            echo "Could not create new click counter.";
         }
         else {
            $clicks = 1;
         }
    } else {
    //get number of clicks for page and add 1     fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)
        while($click_row = $click_insert_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
            $clicks = $row['page_count'] + 1;
            //update click count in database;
            //report error if not updated

            $click_update_stmt = "
            UPDATE click_count
            SET page_count=page_count+1
            WHERE user_id = ?
            AND page_url = ?
            ";
            if(!$click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_update_stmt)) {
                $click_update_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $curPage)); 
                echo "Could not save new click count for this page.";
         }
        }
    }
```

NEWEST CODE:

```
$curPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$clicks = 0;

    $click_sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM click_count
    WHERE user_id = ?
    AND page_url = ?
    ";
    $click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_sql);
    $click_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $curPage));
    $click_stmt_rows = $click_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $page_count = $click_stmt->rowCount();
    if ($page_count == 0) {
        $click_insert_sql = "
            INSERT INTO click_count 
            (user_id, page_url, page_count)
            VALUES(?, ?, ?)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page_count=page_count+1;
        ";
        $click_insert_stmt = $con->prepare($click_insert_sql);
        $click_insert_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $curPage, 1));
    }
```

Comment: I would rather use an [insert on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to minimize the code logic

Comment: For me, This line `if($_SESSION['page'] != $curPage) {` is playing Villain's Role.

Comment: @NanaPartykar Any suggestions on a better alternative?

Comment: First of all, you are setting session as current page. Then, if session is not equal to current page. Then, how it will go inside `if` and execute your queries. Bro.

Comment: After removing the session code, I get the error that `$page_count` is not defined here: `} else if ($page_count == 0) {`... but I define it above that line of code while doing a `rowCount`.

Comment: Tell me. why are you using while loop inside else? Tell me the reason behind it. and, your problem will get solved.

Comment: _"but I define it above that line of code"_ - no, you don't. It is inside the if - and the else if gets executed when ....?

Comment: I updated my code and put it in my question.. Still not working.

Comment: @Paul : You Didn't Respond To Answer Given Below. Atleast Have Courtesy To Respond. People Spend Their Time To Make You All Out Of Trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is a point of failure:

```
//set current page as session variable
$_SESSION['page'] = $curPage;
//do not recount if page currently loaded
if($_SESSION['page'] != $curPage) {
```

You set the value of $_SESSION['page'] to $curPage and right after that you check if the value is different than $curPage. You just set it to that value, so it can't be different

You should check if $_SESSION['page'] is set first, if it's not set, than set it, if it's set, than check the value of it

```
if (isset($_SESSION['page']) && $_SESSION['page'] != $curPage) {
  // increment counter
} else {
  $_SESSION['page'] = $curPage;
  // add new record
}
```

or, if you just use the [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), you can skip all that logic and do:

```
INSERT INTO click_count (user_id, page_url, page_count) VALUES (?, ?,?)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE page_count=page_count+1;
```

You don't need to check if there's a record for that page, you don't have to see the current value. The query will take care of it.
You do have to define a combined unique key though, on user_id and page_url

Comment: If I just simply remove the session code, I get the error that `$page_count` is not defined here: `} else if ($page_count == 0) {`... but I define it above that line of code while doing a `rowCount`.

Comment: The variable $page_count is another point of failure, it's defined inside an if block.
You need to get that variable out of the if also.

Comment: I updated my code and put it in my question. Still not working.

Comment: @Paul please check the updated answer, the INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY part

Comment: Ok, so I made `user_id` and `page_url` a unique key in my database and then I did the `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in my query, however it is now not updating and how would I add the session code back into it? I updated my question at the bottom with the new code.

Comment: Sorry, I should state, it is inserting the first occurrence of being on the page, but doesn't update from that point. And to your mentioning of the `SELECT`, I need that for future modification.

Answer (score 0):

***Changes***

**1)** Remove `if($_SESSION['page'] != $curPage) {`

**2)** I don't know why you wrote this `if(!$click_stmt=$con->prepare($click_insert_stmt)){` in multiple places. If, unfortunately, these prepare statements got fail, Then, how it will prepare & execute the statement.

**3)** `$user_id` is a Mystery for me. Because, I've not seen anywhere you initialized it.

I've updated your code. Have a look.

***Updated Code***

```
$click_sql = "SELECT * FROM click_count WHERE user_id = ? AND page_url = ?";
$click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_sql);
$click_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $curPage));
$page_count = $click_stmt->rowCount();

if ($page_count == 0) {
  $page_count ++;
  $click_insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO click_count (page_url, page_count, user_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
  $click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_insert_stmt);
  if(!$click_insert_stmt->execute(array($curPage, $page_count, $user_id))){
    echo "Could not create new click counter.";
  }
} else {
  $click_update_stmt = "UPDATE click_count SET page_count= page_count+1 WHERE page_url = ? AND user_id = ?";
  $click_stmt = $con->prepare($click_update_stmt);
  if(!$click_update_stmt->execute(array($curPage,$user_id))){
    echo "Could not save new click count for this page.";
  }
}
```